# Can't print data from Future object returing a List of strings

Tags: java, list, future

I have a ReadFromFile class implementing Callable and returning a list of strings. This list of Strings should be displayed in the console, but stranger things it is not displayed. In debugger I see that the list is not empty and the data inside is correct. But it is not displayed.

Here is the code:

ReadFromFile

```
public class ReadFromFile implements Callable<List<String>> {

private File file;

public ReadFromFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}


@Override
public List<String> call() throws Exception {
    String row = null;

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
            data = Arrays.asList(row.split(";"));
        }
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Break");
    }

    return data;
}}
```

Here is the method, where data from future should be assigned to the list to be displayed:

```
 public static void setupShop(List<String> menuItems, Map<String, Integer> stock, Map<String, Float> price) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    menuItems = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).submit(new ReadFromFile(menuFile)).get();


}
```

I excluded the code for maps here, it doesn't influence this case.

But! If I create another list and assign the data from Future to it, data is displayed correctly:

```
 public static void setupShop(List<String> menuItems, Map<String, Integer> stock, Map<String, Float> price) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List <String> menu = new ArrayList<>();

    menu = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).submit(new ReadFromFile(menuFile)).get();

    for (int i = 0; i<menu.size();i++)
    {
        menuItems.add(menu.get(i));
    }
```

So, the question is, why can't I print data from future.get directly?

Comment: Is it possible that your subsequent logic affected the `menuItems`, causing them to become an empty list?

Comment: Not really, the list is not empty, I checked it. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = Arrays.asList(row.split(";"));` this row is wrong, you re-assign the list so the list will take the value of your file's last line.

use `data.addAll(Arrays.asList(row.split(";")));` instead. Maybe the problem is here, assuming that your last line is an empty row

UPDATE:

Here a reproductible minimal working example:

```
public class ReadFromFile implements Callable<List<String>> {

  private File file;

  public ReadFromFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> call() throws Exception {
    String row = null;

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
        data.addAll(Arrays.asList(row.split(";")));
      }
    } catch (IOException i) {
      System.out.println(i.getMessage());
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

Tested with main class

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      List<String> menu = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).submit(new ReadFromFile(new File("src/test.csv"))).get();
      menu.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

CSV file:

```
sfdfdsf;fdsgfdfsg;gfdgff
gfsgfd;fgfdg;gfgdfg
```

Output of main execution:

```
sfdfdsf
fdsgfdfsg
gfdgff
gfsgfd
fgfdg
gfgdfg
```

Comment: Hi, checked that, it didn't help. In fact as I mentioned the list which I get from Future is not empty, I've seen it in debugger.

Comment: I'll update my answer with a working minimal example

Comment: Right, this is working. Thank you. Probably the reason is that I'm trying to print the list in another method and it doesn't work. The other method is very simple:` public static void displayMenu(List<String> menuItems) {
        displayBorder();

        menuItems.forEach(System.out::println);
        displayBorder();
    }`